# Android Studio Media Player Play and Pause

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

Good day sir/ma'am so I was able to play music on `onCreate`. But my problem is I need to stop the music when the button is clicked. The problem is when I type `mpBM.stop()` inside the case

```
r.id.BUTTONNAME:
mpBm.stop();
 break;
```

the `mpBM.stop();` has error it's exactly on mpBM I think the command cannot call the:

```
 MediaPlayer mpBM = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.ceusong);
```

which I declare inside the on create. When I try to put it outside the `onCreate` and and place it below `LinearLayout ll;` at the top of `onCreate`? It has error on the declaration :

`MediaPlayer mpBM = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.ceusong);`

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Btw what I exactly want is when I press any button the music stops.

```
package org.intercode.lifeatceu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class browse extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView presidentmessage, foreword, missionvision, qualitypolicyandobjectives, expectedgraduateattributes, briefhistory,
        fus, degreeprogramofferings, tvAAEP, tvPFOT,tvSGAOFOFA,tvSSAF,tvUSRP,tvCAH,tvEARSA,tvUOAEO,tvCEUMANILA,tvCEUMAKATI
        ,tvCEUMALOLOS,tvAPPEN,tvSCAO,tvPUBLICATIONS,tvCEAAR,tvPOFMOSCDO,tvGR;
LinearLayout ll;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);

    presidentmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presidentmessage);
    foreword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foreword);
    missionvision = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missionvision);
    qualitypolicyandobjectives = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qualitypolicyandobjectives);
    expectedgraduateattributes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expectedgraduateattributes);
    briefhistory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.briefhistory);
    fus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fus);
    degreeprogramofferings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.degreeprogramofferings);
    tvAAEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAAEP);
    tvPFOT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPFOT);
    tvSGAOFOFA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSGAOFOFA);
    tvSSAF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSSAF);
    tvUSRP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUSRP);
    tvCAH = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCAH);
    tvEARSA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEARSA);
    tvUOAEO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUOAEO);
    tvCEUMANILA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCEUMANILA);
    tvCEUMAKATI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCEUMAKATI);
    tvCEUMALOLOS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCEUMALOLOS);
    tvAPPEN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAPPEN);
    tvSCAO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSCAO);
    tvPUBLICATIONS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPUBLICATIONS);
    tvCEAAR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCEAAR);
    tvPOFMOSCDO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPOFMOSCDO);
    tvGR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGR);

    presidentmessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    foreword.setOnClickListener(this);
    missionvision.setOnClickListener(this);
    qualitypolicyandobjectives.setOnClickListener(this);
    expectedgraduateattributes.setOnClickListener(this);
    briefhistory.setOnClickListener(this);
    fus.setOnClickListener(this);
    degreeprogramofferings.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAAEP.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvPFOT.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvSGAOFOFA.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvSSAF.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvUSRP.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvCAH.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvEARSA.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvUOAEO.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvCEUMANILA.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvCEUMAKATI.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvCEUMALOLOS.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvAPPEN.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvSCAO.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvPUBLICATIONS.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvCEAAR.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvPOFMOSCDO.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvGR.setOnClickListener(this);
    final MediaPlayer mpBM = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ceusong);
    mpBM.start();

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.presidentmessage:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, pm.class));
            break;
        case R.id.foreword:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, F.class));
            break;
        case R.id.missionvision:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, cvmgacv.class));
            break;
        case R.id.qualitypolicyandobjectives:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, cqpao.class));
            break;
        case R.id.expectedgraduateattributes:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ceega.class));
            break;
        case R.id.briefhistory:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ceuabh.class));
            break;
        case R.id.fus:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, fus.class));
            break;
        case R.id.degreeprogramofferings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, fus.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvAAEP:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, aaep.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvPFOT:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PFOT.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvSGAOFOFA:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SGAOFOFA.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvSSAF:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SSAF.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvUSRP:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, USRP.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvCAH:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CAH.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvEARSA:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, EARSA.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvUOAEO:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,UOAEO.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvCEUMANILA:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,CEUMANILA.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvCEUMAKATI:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,CEUMAKATI.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvCEUMALOLOS:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,CEUMALOLOS.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvAPPEN:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Appendices.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvSCAO:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Appendices.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvPUBLICATIONS:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PUBLICATION.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvCEAAR:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CEAAR.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvPOFMOSCDO:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, POFMOSCDO.class));
            break;
        case R.id.tvGR:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GR.class));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `mpBM` is local to `onCreate` and therefore isn't visible in `onClick`.

Comment: yes when i move it to be a part of activity class the activity wont just open and error comes from that declaraction

Comment: So move the declaration but keep the initialization in `onCreate` (you'll have to remove the `final`).

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of mpBM to be a member of the activity class rather a local variable in onCreate() so it will be visible in other methods.

Comment: yes when i move it to be a part of activity class the activity wont just open and error comes from that declaraction